# KendoUI Angular2 - Debounce slider

Tags: angular, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-slider

I would like to update a model when the slider change event is triggered +  a debounce time (in order to not stressing too much the layout, since that model is going to be used in a massive chart refreshed every 250ms).

This is the scenario:

HTML

```
    <kendo-slider [min]="1" 
                  [max]="5" 
                  [(ngModel)]="model" 
                  (valueChange)="functionToBeDebounced($event)">
    </kendo-slider>
```

TS

```
 public functionToBeDebounced(value) {
        this.model = value;
        this.notification.emit(this.model);
 }
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
    <kendo-slider [min]="1" 
                  [max]="5" 
                  [(ngModel)]="model" 
                  (valueChange)="functionToBeDebounced($event)"
                  [debounce]="500" >
    </kendo-slider>
```

The result would be calling `functionToBeDebounced` only when the sliding is over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rxjs/Subject to debounce everything you want.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

---

```
private debouncer: Subject<any> = new Subject();

ngOnInit(){
  this.debouncer.debounceTime(500).subscribe(event => {
    this.functionToBeDebounced(event);
  });
}

private callDebouncer(event){
  this.debouncer.next(event);
}
```

---

```
(valueChange)="callDebouncer($event)"
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks! Totally forgot about reactive approach ;)

Comment: Can you make a more generic approach ? For example if you have more than 1 control that requires debouncing.

Comment: @Misi Either use one debouncer for each control or only 1 debouncer but keep track of which control is used within the `callDebouncer` function.

Comment: @Ploppy For using only one debouncer, how would you track witch control needs debouncing ? 

private callDebouncer(control, event) { switch(control) { case "slider1": .. } }  ??

Comment: @Misi $event contains the html element, you could by example identify the controls with their id tag. Then in the `callDebouncer` function, save the active control in a variable (declared in the component). Then in the `subscribe` method you know which control is currently used and with a switch/case you will be able to do whatever you want. I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it, but it should work.